# Compare two records and get the names of the changed columns in rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i need to compare two active records and get the name of the changed column

```
#<Evaluation id: 1, name: "Foo", status: "yes", comments: "can be better", created_at: "2017-05-09 12:00:00", updated_at: "2017-05-09 12:00:00">    
#<Evaluation id: 2, name: "Foo", status: "yes", comments: "keep up the good work", created_at: "2017-05-09 12:05:00", updated_at: "2017-05-09 12:05:00">
```

I need to compare these two records and get the names of the changed columns. In this case `:comments, :created_at, :updated_at`

I have tried using methods like `eql?`, `record1.attributes.except('id') == record2.attributes.except('id')`

These only return either true or false I need to get the column names as well.
This can be done by comparing each column but i am looking for any other option.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a small method to do this for you :

```
def diff_active_record(record_a, record_b)
   (record_a.attributes.to_a - record_b.attributes.to_a).map(&:first)
end
```

This method will take the two active_record objects(in this case : `record_a` , `record_b` ) to compare and generate an array of attribute names that have changed.

You may use it like this:

```
diff_active_record(Evaluation.find(1), Evaluation.find(2))
```

The above would result in `[:id, :comments, :created_at, :updated_at]`

Comment: Interesting to note that there used to be a [`Hash#diff`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/diff) method in Rails versions `3.0.0` - `4.0.2`, but it was then [removed without replacement](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c0c87922baf47eed64a53d3afceba978bb175da9/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/diff.rb#L9). However, it would be pretty easy to re-implement that method just looking at the source code.